Opening a file or folder crashes VSCode
My VSCode version is 1.93.1. I recently upgraded my Ubuntu OS from 22.04 to 24.04, and since then I've been facing a problem with VSCode. The program opens correctly, with my last saved workspaces, I can open new files in the workspace by doing Ctrl + P. However, whenever I try opeing a file or folder like Ctrl + O, the program crashes and shuts down.
I've disabled all extensions, but the issue still keeps getting reproduced.
My VSCode was installed through snap, and many of the solutions I've had suggest uninstalling and installing the .deb package from the official VSCode website. However, I fear losing a lot of preferences and saved settings if I go through that route.
Another solution, which works, suggests running:
code --in-process-gpu

The problem with this solution is you'd have to run it every single time you wish to start VSCode, which is really not convinient.
However, that's what I'm going with now as I await a definitive solution.

Have you tried updating code? Your version seems out of date. I.e, first just sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade - that will typically get you code updates regularly.

If the above has no effect, try instead sudo snap refresh - I'm a little foggy. I think I used to install code with apt and got updates that way ... but maybe this has changed.

I have this issue as well on the currently latest release (1.94.0). There's an issue on it here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/230454
